# Linux Mint 20.2 unable to configure tmux with color terminal

Tags: linux-mint, tmux, gnome-terminal, xfce4-terminal

I am having a problem configuring tmux to display a color prompt. By default I am using:

Gnome-terminal 3.36.2

tmux 3.0a

This is my ~/.tmux.conf

```bash
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
set -g mouse on
```

**Outside** of tmux `$TERM` is `xterm-256color` while **inside** tmux it is `screen-256color`.

I've confirmed also that `~/.tmux.config` is being read using [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1725992/154100) and also by the fact that mouse input works.

Out of curiosity grepping all environment variables for `TERM`:

**Outside tmux-gnome terminal**

```bash
COLORTERM=truecolor
GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN=/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/47863855_a726_437a_b8c9_43962ae12a95
TERM=xterm-256color
GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE=:1.229
```

**Inside tmux - Gnome-terminal**

```bash
COLORTERM=truecolor
GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN=/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/35868158_38eb_4601_c1431ed11596
TERM=xterm-256color
GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE=:1.109
```

I can understand perhaps why `GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN` is a different value but not why `GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE` is.

Installed `xfce4-terminal` and it too does not display in color despite confirming the `TERM` environment variable is correctly set as `screen-256color`

Comment: How do you test if it is displaying color? Do you have an example command? Or just your `$PS1`?

Comment: @Panki $PS1, and also `ls -l` and also I installed `colortest`